# "Configuration settings for ADUtil are invalid!" from SharePoint when trying to delete a site

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to delete a site in my MOSS VM and getting the following error:

```
Configuration settings for ADUtil are invalid!
```

Same thing when trying to restore a site over the existing one with an overwrite flag.  Can't find any references online.

Full trace:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Configuration settings for ADUtil are invalid! ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81072186): Configuration settings for ADUtil are invalid!
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.DeleteSite(String bstrUrl, Boolean bDeleteADAccounts)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DeleteSite(String bstrUrl, Boolean bDeleteADAccounts)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DeleteSite(String bstrUrl, Boolean bDeleteADAccounts)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Delete(Boolean bDeleteADAccounts)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Delete()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteAdministration.Delete()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.DeleteSitePage.BtnDelete_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP._admin_delsite_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we had a feature to prevent site owners from deleting their sites which was checking an AD group before allowing the delete. After disabling the feature, the site deleted just fine.